# Can't test PageSpeed because of redirects : "page reached the limit of 3 client redirects"

Tags: redirect, pagespeed

I have an issue that I'm really not sure how to fix or even how to properly diagnose. When I try to test my page speed with Page Speed Insights, I get this error message:

> Attempting to load the page reached the limit of 3 client redirects.
>   The last URL fetched was **http://vod.humnetwork.com/**. This may
>   indicate the page is redirecting to itself, or has a loop of
>   redirects.

Please help to find cause of this error.

Comment: Having the same problem today, did you work out how to fix it, other than temporarily removing window.location.reload calls (which does "fix" it for me).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.

What I did to solve this issue was removing every `window.location.reload()` that I had in my javascript files that were being used by the page.

Maybe you have the same problem....

Comment: Having the same problem today, did you work out how to fix it, other than temporarily removing window.location.reload calls (which does "fix" it for me).